# Find a class in .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method in jQuery which is receiving a 'this' reference, so that I can filter out all the html by using:

```
showSomeThing = function (e) {
    $("#div").html($(e).html());
}
```

1. I want to do some filtering on this e before passing that to the div, e.g. I want to find a class named 'someclass' and set it's display to 'none' so that the class will not show in div above.

I'm trying this:

```
$("#div").html($(e).find("someclass").hide().html();
```

but it doesn't work.

2. I also want to search some particular attributes in the html and their values (once I am able to do the above).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.end()` , `.attr()`

```
$("#div").html(
  $(e).find("someclass").hide()
  .attr({name:"newName", value:"newValue"})
  .end()
  .html()
);
```

Comment: Only one thing is missing, e contains all the html inside it but doesn't contain the html and attributes of the passed element, how to include them?

Comment: @sam Try substituting `[0].outerHTML` for `.html()` following `.end()` to include `html` of  `e` element

Comment: I tried this but didn't work:
 $("#div").html($(e).find(".someclass").hide().end().outerHTML())
but didn't work, am i missing something?

Comment: @sam _"missing something?"_ `[0]` before `.outerHTML` . `[0]` returns `DOM` element ; could alternatively use `.get().outerHTML` `.get()` is a jQuery method that returns `DOM` element

Comment: Thanks, I did:
hide().end()[0].outerHTML
and it worked